# Maximum path length in a path-connected domain with smooth boundary

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology, plane-geometry

I have an open, bounded, connected, and simply connected domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with smooth boundary. I'd like to prove that there is a constant $M$ so that any two points in the domain can be connected by a smooth curve of length at most $M$.

I was imagining a counterexample of some kind of interior spiral where the path can become arbitrarily long as it spirals inward, but it seems that the smooth boundary would prevent this kind of thing.

One thing I considered was taking any path connecting two points of $\Omega$, covering the path with open balls, taking a finite subcover, connecting the centers to get a chain of straight segment paths, and smoothing the corners with some kind of mollification, but this seems like it may be overkill, and doesn't necessarily give a uniform bound on the total path length.

I also considered that you could move from each point to the nearest boundary point, and connect the paths along the boundary, which seems that a bound like $M=\text{(perimeter of }\Omega)+2(\text{diameter of }\Omega$) could work, but I'm sure this is not precise enough.

I would appreciate any advice or references!

Comment: If you are familiar with Riemann's mapping theorem and Painleve's smooth version of it, there is a fairly straightforward proof: just notice that your question is clearly positive for the unit disc and that by the two theorem above the conformal factor is bounded on $\Omega$ and you're done

Comment: @Pelota Thank you for the reply, I am now looking at Theorem 3.1 on page 238 of https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1990-22-02/S0273-0979-1990-15879-3/S0273-0979-1990-15879-3.pdf, which proves that "a biholomorphic map of a bounded simply connected planar domain with smooth boundary onto the unit disc extends smoothly up to the boundary."

So if I take a Riemann mapping T from my domain onto the unit disc, how do I translate that into a bound on the minimum length of paths connecting points? I'm unsure what you mean by "the conformal factor is bounded." I'd appreciate any further advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $d:\Omega \times \Omega \to [0,\infty),\,(p,q)\mapsto d(p,q) = \inf\{L(\gamma):\gamma\in C^1([0,1],\Omega),\gamma(0) = p, \gamma(1) = q\}$ is the distance between two points in $\Omega$, where $L(\gamma) := \int_0^1 |\gamma'(t)| dt$. The function $d$ is continuous and we want to show that it is bounded. The clue is, that we can continuously extend $d$ to $\overline \Omega \times \overline \Omega$. Then, $d$ is bounded, as it is continuous on a compact set.

For the statement about extendability, let $p\in \Omega$ and take a point $q\in \partial \Omega$ on the boundary. Choose a sequence of points $q_k \in \Omega$ converging to $q$ and apply the continuity of $d$ inside $\Omega\times \Omega$ to get a limit $d(p,q) := \lim_{k\to\infty} d(p,q_k)$
which doesn't depend on the sequence $(q_k)_k$ (this is the difficult part where we one needs to apply the definition of smooth boundary). This yields a continuous extension on $\Omega \times \overline \Omega$. Repeat the argument for the first component to get an extension on $\overline \Omega \times \overline \Omega$.

Comment: Right approach but you have to do more work on proving existence of a continuous extension (this is where smoothness of the boundary will be used).

Comment: This seems promising and I appreciate your response. I accepted the answer but am having trouble with the "difficult part." 

I know that the boundary being smooth means that, at each boundary point q, there is a smooth function f defined on an open ball $B(q)$ so that: 1) f>0 in $\Omega \cap B$; 2) f=0 on $\partial\Omega\cap B$; 3) f has a smooth inverse (definition from section 6.2 of Gilbarg-Trudinger).

Say I have the setup you gave. Eventually $\{q_k\}\subset B(q)$. At this point I know $f\in C^\infty$ should come into play but I'm stuck here. I'd appreciate any advice!

Comment: I think you need to work with the triangle inequality that holds for $d:\Omega\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. This can be used to get estimates for $|d(p,q_k)-d(p,q_l)|$ and to prove that $d(p,q_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence and converges to a limit. The estimates from the triangle inequality should imply, that this limit is unique.

Comment: From the comment it appears that you do not know how to solve the difficult part of the problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is the way to go. I would recommend using another way of describing smooth boundary, namely by using a flattening diffeomorphism. Since $\Omega$ is compact, the boundary $\partial\Omega$ is compact and can be covered by finitely many of these diffeomorphisms $\phi_k$. You can use the supremum $\sup\Vert D\phi_k\Vert$ to estimate distances using the mean value theorem. Since you have finitely many $\phi_k$, you can take the maximum of these constants. I hope that helps